# Call LightBox onclick without using <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, lightbox

For an image gallery i use lightbox for opening the images. The way i call it is trough an < a > tag with  a data-rel as below.

```
<a href="../catalog-reseller/wall/abstract/w10197169324.jpg" data-rel="lightcase:gallery" title="w10197169324">
```

Is it possible to call the exact same thing onclick without using < a >?

My complete code is:

```
<div class="justified">             
   <a href="../catalog-reseller/wall/abstract/w10197169324.jpg" data-rel="lightcase:gallery" title="w10197169324">
        <img src="../catalog-reseller/wall/abstract/w10197169324.jpg" alt="w10197169324">
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to add some buttons that appear on image hover like add to cart or add to favourite. The problem is that the < a > affects everything that is in the image area so the buttons are useless because anywhere i click it openes the image.
I thought that making the link inactive and calling lightbox onclick of a separate button would be a solution.

Comment: `data-rel` is unique to the `<a>` tag. Why exactly do you want to use another tag? This sounds like an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), which you may be approaching the [**wrong way**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676); it seems like an unusual thing to want to do. What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? What should the end result be? How does **this approach** help you get there? Please provide some **context** surrounding your question to help clarify your **intent**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to move buttons over the link. For example, create the structure like this:

```
<div class="justified">             
   <a href="../catalog-reseller/wall/abstract/w10197169324.jpg" data-rel="lightcase:gallery" title="w10197169324">
        <img src="../catalog-reseller/wall/abstract/w10197169324.jpg" alt="w10197169324">
    </a>
    <button>Add to cart</button>
</div>
```

and then use CSS to make your button absolute positioned.

Comment: Also, if you would be using fancybox (http://fancyboxjs.com), then you could simply add `data-fancybox` and `data-src` attributes to parent element to enable fancybox (you can add these attributes to any element)

Answer (score 0):

A decent, yet maybe not so eloquent solution would be to use a jQuery mouseenter method (for the element you want to create the hover effect for) - and use jquery to disable that anchor tag during the hover and then a mouseleave to reactivate the anchor... You should add an id to the anchor and image to make it easier.

```
//HTML:

  <a id="removeOnHover" ...>
  <img id="hoverHere"...>

//jQuery:
  $( '#hoverHere' )
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $( '#removeOnHover').attr( 'disabled', 'true' );
      //any other code you need...
  })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $( '#removeOnHover').attr( 'disabled', 'false' );
      //any other code you need...
    });
```

Something like this should help.